# System Information via VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve System Information via VBA code?

Is there such a class as - SystemInfo Class in Excel VBA to do this task?

thanks

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147886 Also check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx Try Google for more links :)

Comment: There are many ways to access system information, can you refine the question to tell us what specific system information are you looking for so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Each Office application's VBA has different classes available.

For example:- to find out which OS is running, Word has a 'System' class containing `System.OperatingSystem`.  That provides a text string.  Excel has the same OperatingSystem object but under the Application class, so to get the same info in Excel you use `Application.OperatingSystem`.

A full reference of the objects available to you is provided in the Object Browser (F2 from within the VBA editor.)

Failing that you can find out just about anything from a WMI Query.
See  http://accesstips.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/using-the-power-of-vbscripts-in-microsoft-access-vba/ for an example.